# Using GlobalFlags to call vsjitdebugger with VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7

I've upgraded to Win7 and VS2010. Previously on Win2K and VS2008, I used GlobalFlags to debug an application on startup, simply by setting it's debugger to vsjitdebugger - see the screenshot below. Unfortunately, this doesn't work on my current setup - a google and search of SO haven't turned up any answers.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** Forgot to mention that my global flags settings do seem to have some effect - running my command on the command line causes Windows to say the program has crashed - it works just fine without the global flags. This is leading me to think my command line for the debugger is incorrect - but that's just a guess. I'd be interested in hearing from anyone who's got this to work.

[alt text http://img825.imageshack.us/img825/3538/55489547.png](http://img825.imageshack.us/img825/3538/55489547.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there's an extra step in Win7 which I wasn't expecting - it throws up a "MyProgram has stopped working" screen first. If you look at the details, it says it's an application crash.

You get the options:

- "Check online for a solution and close the program"
- "Close the program"
- "Debug the program"

Clicking debug then pops up the vsjitdebugger dialog and all is well.

Answer (score 2):

Running the 64-bit version of Windows 7? Using the 32-bit version of gflags.exe?

You can also edit the registry directly.  An example .reg file for notepad.exe:

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\notepad.exe]
"Debugger"="vsjitdebugger.exe"
```

Comment: I am actually using a 64 bit version of Windows but I have tried both versions. I'm actually trying to debug a 32-bit app if that makes any difference. 

I will try the registry setting in the morning - thanks.

Comment: The 32-bit key is in HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\etc

Comment: yeah - it'll be interesting to see if it works. What gets me is what's the difference between my old setup and the new one - Win7 strikes me as the most obvious culprit.

Comment: Of course not, it is running your first 64-bit operating system.  There will be other surprises...

Comment: haha - no, I'm a 64-bit "veteran" so I've been bitten at one stage or another by a lot of the surprises :)

Comment: The respective key in the *Wow6432Node* is automatically updated. No need to manually change anything. Just adding the key under the location stated in your answer is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Run the VS2010 on Win7 with administrator privilege, "vsjitdebugger.exe" works fine.