# How do I force DebugBreak() to give me the option to debug?

Tags: debugging, windows-7, crash

I am trying to debug an application that is spawned using a `CreateProcess` and immediately debug it. I have read a `DebugBreak()` should allow this, however when the process starts, Windows reports an APPCRASH and only allows 'Close application' or 'check for solutions and close application', the familiar 'close', 'debug' dialog doesn't appear.

Generally, how can I force this window to appear, with or without `DebugBreak()`?

**Edit:** Using VC++ Express

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3400220/17034

Comment: Thanks Hans, interesting concept, I am still trying to find a permutation that works with it though. So far I get the debugger launched, but no breakpoints get hit because it loads up its own solution with no associated code...

Comment: Just have another instance of VS ready to go with the solution loaded.  Select it in the jit dialog.

Comment: It is launching a fresh instance each time, however I don't have vsjitdebugger.exe so I have been looking at the alternatives and the Microsoft solution that is similar to yours: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed(vs.71).aspx. In that it suggests using devenv.exe /debugexe. Unfortunately I am using the express version vcexpress.exe /debugexe. This is what is being launched (eight times as eight new processes are spawned in this system.)

Comment: Hmm, clearly you are using the wrong tooling to get the job done.  A free version of VS is only without cost if your time is free.  Do not omit details like that in your question btw.

Comment: Understandable, apologies for the confusion. I know the express version is insufficient, but often it is hard to come up with a definitive list of necessary features missing to put together a justification for getting better tools.